# "Народ, да!" или "Да, народ!"?

Tags: перевод, английский

In the  [book](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1595398/) with translations of American folklore published in the USSR in 1983 to celeberate 25 years of  Soviet-American friendship the translators decided to use the title "Народ, да!" for "Yes, folks!".

Though from my feeling of both languages, in Russian "Народ, да!" makes generally not very much sense and in this specific context actually no sense at all as "Yes, folks!" seems to be some narrative expression.

[image]

Would you say "Народ, да!" is correct? Where would you find it in other contexts? Or is Да, народ..!" more correct? In the sense, "такие вот дела!"

Comment: to me the original title doesn't make sense, not sure how much the variant **Такие (вот) дела, ребята! (Так-то/Вот так, ребята!)** is congruent with the content of the book but it's indeed idiomatic unlike the original... even the communist tinted **Да, товарищи!** as a phrase would come off better, ***Товарищи, да!*** is awkward...

Comment: on another note, are you sure it was to celebrate the friendship, considering that is was published in the midst of the Cold War?

Comment: strange enough, yes - it is referenced as "25 years of diplomatic relationship" so friendship is not the right term. Nevertheless the book does not provide a feeling to study you enemy.

Comment: for me, "Вот так, ребята!" comes very close to "Yes, folks!" but it might be misconcepted as talking to children, that is the book does not have really adult content but it is not too much of a chidren book.

Comment: the word **Народ** can occasionally be used to address a group of people but it's very unlikely to feature in affirming or negating statements directed at such a group due to creating an artificial distance between them and the speaker and sounding somewhat haughty, but this is in a live setting of immediate interaction... in principle **ребята** could be a marker of children oriented content, but that could be mitigated by appropriate cover

Comment: Народ can be referring to a small group of friends colloquially, but it's not a good translation for a folk tales book. I agree with ребята or even друзья (though it's not a literate translation, it conveys the mood better). And yes, да sounds better in front. Also agree that такие [вот] дела  or вот так would work better.

Comment: It's not "Yes, folks!", it's "The People, Yes" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_People,_Yes

Answer (score 2):

The title of the Russian book is a reference to 1936's poem [The People, Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_People,_Yes) by Carl Sandburg.

"The people, yes, the people" is a refrain and a recurring theme in this poem.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the original title (where people are *addressed*), its Russian translation sounds too indefinite. **Народ** can mean *addressed people*, *people of the whole country* or a *crowd of people*. So the expression "Да, народ!" (with either word order) *without a context* can mean something different in reverse translation:

> Yes, it's about our nation! (It's about our nation, yes!)

So, some other translation version, e.g. "Да, люди!" (where people are addressed informally) was worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. As an American born to a Russian speaking mother (meaning I may be very off base), it sounds better in the order that it is written. <<Народ, да!>>, to me, sounds more grandiose. Also, putting народ first, I think, could serve to call for people's attention to да, or the да could be describing the народ. To me, however, <<Да, народ>> could sound more like a confirmation that we are indeed talking about the народ, or be like a response of да to the people.

Comment: Lucas, it's about context relevant translation of "yes, folks!" typical for  narration of the tales and pre-urban legends featured in the book. Note that's not "yes, folk!"

Comment: This is the only correct answer here) The title in English means "Yes to the people!/ People, Yes!. Thus the most important part is the word "yes", which goes at the end.